# QGIS Points in polygon - Difference between zero, and cells with no value?

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, null

I've carried out a points in polygon analysis. My output data contains the following results:

```
PolygonID    Point.Count
1            3
2            0
3           
4            1
5            0
6            8  
7         
8            4
```

Evidently, the analysis is working in that it returned values for most polygons. However, some polygons have no values at all?

It is clear what polygons with a value of zero mean - there are no points within the polygon boundary in question.

However, why would some be returned with no values?

Can I treat these the same as zero? Or, is this perhaps a bug in QGIS?

**EDIT:**

Using QGIS Version 2.14

I took a CSV file with lat-long coordinates in `WGS84` and then saved it as a shapefile.

This shapefile was then imported into a new project and re-saved as `EPSG:27700`.

It was then imported into a project with my polygons that were already in `EPSG:27700`, to carry out the points in polygon analysis.

Comment: which version of qgis? also, what's the source of your polygon layer (e.g. shapefile / database table / delimited file...). Gut feel says it could be EMPTY geometries, especially if you're using delimited file.

Comment: Steven, I have edited my answer to include this information now. Any ideas?